# Callback without effect, function still executed before callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I have a function with a callback, my problem is that the return of the function happens before the callback ad then return null instead of returning me the array of coordinates

```js
function callback(coordinates=[]){
    console.log(coordinates);
    return coordinates;
}
 function getCoordinates(callback){
    connection.connect();
    let coordinates=[null];
    connection.query('SELECT AreaId AS areaNumber, longitude AS longitude, latitude AS latitude FROM coordinates', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        let area=[];
        for (result of results) {
            if (!area.includes(result.areaNumber)){
                area.push(result.areaNumber)
                coordinates[result.areaNumber]=[];
            }
            coordinate=[result.longitude,result.latitude];
            coordinates[result.areaNumber].push(coordinate);
        }    
        coordinates=callback(coordinates)
    });
    connection.end();
    return coordinates;
}
console.log(getCoordinates(callback));
```

and I have :

> [null] //correspond to console.log(getCoordinates(callback));

and

> [array with value] // corresponding to console.log(coordinates) in function vallback

How to do for that my callback will be considered?
Sorry I am kind of new on node.js so I may have missunderstood callback.
What I would like is to get an array of coordinates that I can use later on at 2 different places in my code like :

```js
.get('/map', function(req, res) {
    let Coords=getCoordinate(callback)
    res.render('map.ejs', {token: tokenMapbox, coordinates: Coords});
})
.get('/wmap', function(req, res) {
    let Coords=getCoordinate(callback)
    res.render('wmap.ejs', {token: tokenMapbox, coordinates: Coords});
})
```

Comment: Forget about the return values. The code that needs to work with `coordinates` should be located in the callback. This might help: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html , especially "Misconception 1: Returning from the callback"

Comment: *"What I would like is to get an array of coordinates that I can use later on at 2 different places in my code."* Depends on what "later on" really means and what the two places. But generally there should be a problem to just put all the code that needs the data in side the callback. With a more complete example we could help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to this problem, however if you wish to use the resulting coordinates in a similar way to synchronous code, I suggest you try using the async/await syntax. If you call your query from an async function you can use the *await* keyword to provide more readable code.

Once you have your coordinates variable populated in your async function you can do what you wish with it.

For example:

```
function getCoordinates() {
    connection.connect();
    let coordinates = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query('SELECT AreaId AS areaNumber, longitude AS longitude, latitude AS latitude FROM coordinates', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                let area=[];
                for (result of results) {
                    if (!area.includes(result.areaNumber)){
                        area.push(result.areaNumber)
                        coordinates[result.areaNumber]=[];
                    }
                    coordinate=[result.longitude,result.latitude];
                    coordinates[result.areaNumber].push(coordinate);
                }    
                resolve(coordinates);
                connection.end();
            }
        });
    })
}

async function testCoordinates() {
    let coordinates = await getCoordinates();
    console.log("Coordinates:", coordinates);
    // You can do whatever you wish with the coordinates variable
}

testCoordinates();
```

Comment: console.log("Coordinates:", coordinates); inside async function testCoordinates() i can but return coordinate right ? because then it return me {promise}

Comment: When you use the await keyword, you won't get a promise, you'll get the coordinates array! It's really quite similar to using .then(), only with different (and IMHO) more readable syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing different things. Let me explain

First thing, forget about the term "callback". We'll understand this simply as a function passsed as parameter to another function. Don't worry about it, I'm going to explain.

So we start from the problem: **how to fetch array of coordinates from database and print it**

Next thing you get to know about interacting with database and assuming this is how your library works: it has a function `connection.query(myQuery, someFunction)` which can get you results from database.

Now first thing you notice about that query function is it's parameters. `myQuery` is a string and `someFunction` is a function definition. While we have seen in other languages that we pass values such as numbers, string, etc. as parameters to a function, interestingly in javascript you can pass on a function definition as a parameter as well. And this is what makes javascript powerful, you can pass on function definition as parameter.

Wow, passing on function as parameter, but how does that work? 
Let's take a different example; let's say here I want to create a function which will do some calculations

```
//Here myVar is a variable and doSomething is a function
function interestingJsFunction(myVar, doSomething){
   var twiceOfVar = 2*myVar;
   doSomething(twiceOfVar);
   var thriceOfVar = 3*myVar;
   doSomething(thriceOfVar);
}
```

So what does this function do? It applies some calculations and calls the function doSomething at some points; at one point it passes twice value of myVar to function and at one point it passes thrice of myVar. But what this function `doSomething` do is not defined as of now. And you can define it by passsing your own function as parameter. This gives you infinite possibilities. How?

```
interestingJsFunction(2, function(result){ console.log(result) })
interestingJsFunction(2, function(result){ console.log("the new behaviour" + result) })
//And so on...
```

You understand how this has made one interestingJsFunction useful in different cases. If you knew that you would need only one implementation of doSomething(), you could have simply removed the `doSomething` from parameters and whatever you wanted to do, you could have done that directly inside interestingJsFunction(e.g. console.log(twiceOfVar))

Now coming back to the `query` function. It is also an interestingJsFunction and if you go to definition of `query` function(you can dig up the code of your library to see what's inside query function) you'll find that it does some operations on database, gets the results and call the function[similar to `doSomething`] which was passed as parameter, if it gets any error while doing so, it calls the function in parameter and passes error to it.

When it does so, it sends back error, results and field as parameter to this function. So now you can utilize these paramaeters in your function which was passed as parameter. It's upto you now how you want to utilize this, it could be that you can simply print the results as following (remember how we used interestingJsFunction?)

```
//We could simply print the results if there are any
connection.query(myQuery, function(error, results, fields){ 
    if(results) console.log(results.toString()) 
})

//Or we could throw erorr if there's any
connection.query(myQuery, function(error, results, fields){ 
    if(error) throw error 
})

//Guess what would happen when you return something inside this function?
var myQueryFunction = connection.query(myQuery, function(error, results, fields){ 
    return "return of query function"
})


//And guess what would happen when you have something like this
function myNewFunction(){
    var x = connection.query(myQuery, function(error, results, fields){ 
        return "return of query function"
    })
    return "return of myNewFunction"
}
```

I leave last 2 exercises for you and you should be able to fix the problems after that. Try console.log statements to understand

Comment: Some feedback: Overall correct, but the choice of words is a bit imprecise. For example: *"Interesting, you can not just pass on a variable as parameter but you can pass on a function as parameter as well."* You are mixing two things here: A function is a *value* in JavaScript, a *variable* is basically a container that holds a *value*. You are comparing apples and oranges. Variables are actually not passed as parameters, values are. Variables are just one means to provide that value (evaluating the variable results in the value it holds).

Comment: That's right. @felix-kling thanks for correcting. Editing now.